# C++: The average output of my program doesn't show properly

Tags: c++

I've already had searched around the internet for some answers, but I can't seem to find the answer. I guess this program would be easier if I use for loop but my professor ordered us to use the while loop statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float value[10];
    float average;
    float min;
    float max;
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, index3 = 0, index4 = 0, sum;

    while (index1 < 10)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value : ";
        cin >> value[index1];
        index1++;
    }
    while (index2 < 10)
    {
        sum += value[index2];
        index2++;
    }

    max = value[index3];
    while (index3 < 10)
    {
        if (max < value[index3])
        {
            max = value[index3];
        }
        index3++;
    }
    min = value[index4];
    while (index4 < 10)
    {
        if (min > value[index4])
        {
            min = value[index4];
        }
        index4++;
    }
    average = sum / 10;
    cout << "The average is        : " << average << "\n";
    cout << "The largest value is  : " << max << "\n";
    cout << "The smallest value is : " << min << "\n";
}
```

Here's how it looks when I run it.

```
Enter a value : 98
Enter a value : 45
Enter a value : 32
Enter a value : 21
Enter a value : 67
Enter a value : 54
Enter a value : 74
Enter a value : 25
Enter a value : 98
Enter a value : 33
The average is        : -2.00668e+008
The largest value is  : 98
The smallest value is : 21
```

Comment: You're not initializing `sum`

Comment: There are several things wrong with this program, all of which would still be wrong if you used a for loop. The main problem is that you forgot `sum = 0` at the beginning of your code. Another problem is that you are performing integer division when you compute the average, change the code to `average = sum / 10.0;` to get floating point division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Move variables outside of the main function globally and there is no need to initialize them. Also, you can do calculations using only one loop.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float value[10], average, min, max, sum;
int index;

int main()
{
   while (index < 10)
   {
        cout << "Enter a value : ";
        cin >> value[index];
     
        if (value[index] > max) max = value[index];
        if (value[index] < min) min = value[index];
        sum += value[index];

        index++;
   }

   average = sum / 10.0;
   cout << "The average is        : " << average << "\n";
   cout << "The largest value is  : " << max << "\n";
   cout << "The smallest value is : " << min << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The variable 'sum' should be a float type instead of int ,  unless of it summation  get truncated (since value is a float type).

Comment: @gobinda Right, thanks. I just copied his code and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the result of integer division, and uninitialized variables. Divide by `10.0` rather than `10` so that compiler coerces both values to a floating point number. Also assign 0 to sum when you are declaring it.

I am assuming there are other warnings too in your program since you are implicitly assigning floating point values to an integer too.

Answer (score 0):

sum should be equal to zero at point of declaring otherwise it will have garbage value.
int index1 = 0, index2 = 0, index3 = 0, index4 = 0, sum = 0;